# Having trouble setting moderators for Facebook comments social plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-comments

I am attempting to add a moderator for the Facebook comments social plugging using the code below. It seems no matter what Facebook User ID I enter the only user that can moderate is the one who is set as the app admin (on the Facebook side). Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>  
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
    <meta property="fb:moderator" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
  </head> 
  <body>    
    <div id="fb-root"></div> 
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&amp;xfbml=1"></script> 
    <fb:comments href="" numposts="10" width="480" colorscheme="dark" migrated=1> </fb:comments> 
    </div>
    <div id="user-info"></div>
    <p>
      <button id="fb-auth">
        Login
      </button>
    </p>
    <script>                                     
      //Facebook
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {       
        FB.init({ 
          appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
      status: true, 
      cookie: true,
      xfbml: true,
      oauth: true
             });

      function updateButton(response) {      
        var button = document.getElementById('fb-auth');
        if (response.authResponse) {
          //user is already logged in and connected
          var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
          var actionInfo = document.getElementById('action-info');
          FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            userInfo.innerHTML = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + response.id + '/picture">' + response.name;
             button.innerHTML = 'Logout';
                                            });          
          button.onclick = function() {
            FB.logout(function(response) {
              var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
              userInfo.innerHTML="";
                                      });
                                       };
                                    } else {
           //user is not connected to your app or logged out
           button.innerHTML = 'Login';
           button.onclick = function() {
             FB.login(function(response) {
           if (response.authResponse) {
                 FB.api('/me', function(response) {
               var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
               userInfo.innerHTML = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'  + response.id + '/picture" style="margin-right:5px"/>' + response.name;
                                              });      
                                          } else {
                   //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization
                                                 }
                                          } 
                                          ,{scope:'email'}
                      );    
                                        }
                                            }
                                          }
             // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
             FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
             FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton); 
                                            };

             (function() {
               var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
               e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
               document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
                          }());
          </script>
      </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I hope you get an answer,  I've been struggling with this too.

Comment: Looks like a lot of people have. Please post if you figure it out and I'll to the same.

Comment: Can't you do this through the actual comment widget itself? I believe it's in one of the context menus.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments), you should register your website as an app and then you can manage moderators through the administrative interface and not have to hard code the moderators in.